# React Native different entry file for different flavor

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my RN project (RN version 0.64.2) I have multiple flavors and I am trying to have different entry file for my different flavor. In my main.java file I have this code

```
@Override
protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
    if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("elev"))
      return "index";
    else return "index.foresatte";
}
```

in my build.gradle file I have this

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    entryFileforesatte: "index.foresatte.js",
    bundleInRelease: true,
    bundleInelevRelease: true,
    bundleInforesatteRelease: true,
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]




 productFlavors {
        elev {
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            applicationId 'com.cgi.oslomelding'
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            dimension "default"
        }
        foresatte {
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            applicationId 'com.cgi.oslomelding.foresatte'
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            dimension "default"

        }
    }
```

when I run npx react-native run-android --variant elevRelease it works fine but when I run npx react-native run-android --variant foresatteRelease it make the elev app. Thing to notice is that the icon is correct but the entry file is wrong.

In debug mode everything works fine. I assume it has something to do with the bundle, maybe.

Comment: Did you able to manage to get it work?